# setting up two ghost blogs, using two domains on one server using nginx

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog

set up is: 2 different domains, 2 separate blog installs of GHOST on one nginx ubuntu 18.04 LTS server

Right now domain A and domain B both point to GHOST blog A. I want Domain A to point to GHOST BLOG A and Domain B to point to GHOST BLOG B.

Both domains point to the same server IP via DNS.

Please see my config config.json files as follows for Ghost:

**Blog A**

```
{
  "url": "https://til.technology",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "dbu",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "db"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/html/til.technology/content"
  },
  "bootstrap-socket": {
    "port": 8000,
    "host": "localhost"
  }
}
```

**Blog B**

```
{
  "url": "https://losing.ink",
  "server": {
    "port": 2370,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "database": {
    "client": "mysql",
    "connection": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "user": "dbu2",
      "password": "pw2",
      "database": "db2"
    }
  },
  "mail": {
    "transport": "Direct"
  },
  "logging": {
    "transports": [
      "file",
      "stdout"
    ]
  },
  "process": "systemd",
  "paths": {
    "contentPath": "/var/www/html/losing.ink/content"
  },
  "bootstrap-socket": {
    "port": 8000,
    "host": "localhost"
  }
}
```

And the nginx server blocks as follow:

and **Blog A**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name til.technology www.til.technology;
    root /var/www/html/til.technology/system/nginx-root;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

**Blog B**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name losing.ink www.losing.ink;
    root /var/www/html/losing.ink/system/nginx-root;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2370;
        proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

Comment: First of all, please, accept my edit so the database credentials (that look pretty much real) get anonymized and noone can try to enter.

Comment: Here's how I did it using the ghost cli tool in two separate subdirectories: http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2020/06/27/installing-ghost-on-aws-lightsail-with-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was doing everything mostly right, however it seemed there was a bug in the CLi installer for Ghost, and they have fixed the issue in the latest update, released a few hours ago. Thanks